# How to have a "Back button style" in the UINavigatorBar / Button

Tags: ios, button

I have a UINavigatorBar and dropped a button to the left top corner in the Interface Builder.

Simple question:
The Button is round, how I can set the button to a "back-style" button? 
(I mean, that the left side of the button is not round, it should be a arrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the back button to go back to the last view in the hierarchy, just leave the button off of the top left corner, and it should show up automatically.

Otherwise, you may need to subclass UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 3):

I just put together a simple `UIViewController` subclass that adds a customizable back button that allows you to change text colors. It basically adds some `willAppear`/`willDisappear` logic to animate the back button the way the `UINavigationController` does while using the `leftBarButtonItem` property. You'd just have to swap out the back-button PNG and change your colors in a subclass.

https://github.com/typeoneerror/BBCustomBackButtonViewController

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to do this with a UINavigationBar that does not work in conjunction with a UINavigationController you need to create a custom view for the button that is shaped like the back button.

Comment: Thats very ugly, only for having a arrow on the left side?!

Comment: You don't need to make a custom view, but you do set a UIButton as a custom view on the UIBarButtonItem. You'll also need to set your own background images on that UIButton.